# i am getting an error using subprocess command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

This is the python code

```
import subprocess

cmd = "HelloWorld.c"
# Example
# cmd = HelloWorld.c
print("Hey this is Python Script Running\n")
subprocess.call(["gcc", cmd])  # For Compiling
subprocess.call("./a.out", shell = True)

# end thats all
```

This is the C code

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     printf("Hello World\n");
     printf("This C program Running\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

This is the Error Code.

Hey this is Python Script Running

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yogi/PycharmProjects/Last_Subprocess_Try/Subprocess/Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["gcc", cmd])  # For Compiling
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you have `gcc` in your search path? I can only get that error if I call a non-existent executable.

Comment: I am running this i Pycharm Community edition 2019,can u please elaborate on how to add the GCC path.

Answer (score 0):

you should give exact HelloWorld.c path

```
cmd = "/home/user/../HelloWorld.c"
```

Comment: Python does not throw an error if the *executable* cannot run with the given arguments. `gcc` would just say "gcc: error: hello: No such file or directory"

Comment: sorry you're wrong. this is subprocess error comes from OS not python. so file path is wrong

Comment: cmd ="/Users/Yogi/Desktop/Pycharm Old Projects/Last_Subprocess_Try/Subprocess/HelloWorld.c"
I gave the pull path ,but its not working still
@Beyhan Gul

Comment: .. but I *tried* it! If `gcc` cannot be located I get the exact `FileNotFoundError` the OP reports. Python does not care at all if gcc cannot find the file.

Comment: Can you please help with how to rectify this gcc error -– usr2564301

Comment: @usr2564301 i have gcc and i got this error. please check.. gcc: error: HelloWorld.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files

Comment: The file is located right in the package directory ,so the input file is located right in the same project file  – Beyhan Gül

Comment: @BeyhanGül: So you get **a different error** than the OP. That is kind of my point.

Comment: yes true. my bad sorry. @TheBatman you should give gcc path correctly. firslty be sure it's installed correctly

Comment: I Dont know how to check if gcc is installed in pycharm,can u please tell me how to do it